Taking skewness into account when determining daily expected ranges
I use a method to determine daily expected ranges by combining both daily IV and daily realized vol. with different weights to get the expected range, and it worked pretty accurately.
However I want to finetune by taking the skewness into account.
My idea is to meassure the 20D and 5D trailing skewness and weight the value of the last 5 days.
Is there any legit way to adjust the daily sigmas by skewness?
Which one is better: meassuring the skewness of logreturns or the skewness of daily realized volatility? (I use a modified GKYZ formula)
kind regards
(I'm talking about SPX)

Not sure if it is correct to incorporate skewness into standard deviation because they are different moments of a probability distribution.

It makes very little sense to mix realized and implied vol. If it matches existing data closely it's just that you data mined it to match current observations. You can use methods like Malz to get risk neutral implied distributions bit they usually aren't particularly useful because they aren't real world probabilities.
